# NullPointerException at ListViewAutoScrollHelper.canTargetScrollVertically (ListViewAutoScrollHelper.java:73)

Tags: android, crash, android-10.0

I have bug report in Google Play Console.
I found no one line of my code in this stack trace - so I don't understand what is the source of this crash.
Can anybody help me?

Yesterday, 6:56 AM on app version 158
Samsung Galaxy A50 (a50), 3840MB RAM, Android 10
Report 1 of 3

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at androidx.core.widget.ListViewAutoScrollHelper.canTargetScrollVertically (ListViewAutoScrollHelper.java:73)
  at androidx.core.widget.AutoScrollHelper.shouldAnimate (AutoScrollHelper.java:506)
  at androidx.core.widget.AutoScrollHelper.onTouch (AutoScrollHelper.java:485)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.DropDownListView.onForwardedEvent (DropDownListView.java:529)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ForwardingListener.onTouchForwarded (ForwardingListener.java:276)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ForwardingListener.onTouch (ForwardingListener.java:97)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner.onTouchEvent (AppCompatSpinner.java:420)
  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent (View.java:14376)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3857)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3535)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3863)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3551)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:729)
  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1922)
  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:4051)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent (WindowCallbackWrapper.java:69)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:687)
  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:14644)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:6522)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:6309)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:5747)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:5800)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5766)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5922)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5774)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5979)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:5747)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:5800)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5766)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5774)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:5747)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:8906)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:8767)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

can you check your code like this?

```
final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
final ListViewAutoScrollHelper scrollHelper = new ListViewAutoScrollHelper(list);
scrollHelper.setEnabled(true);
list.setOnTouchListener(scrollHelper);
```

and please post your using `ListViewAutoScrollHelper` code

Comment: I don't use ListView or ListViewAutoScrollHelper classes in my code.
I use ViewPager class for swiping from left to right. And inside viewpagers I have fragments with ScrollView:

<ScrollView
                android:padding="@dimen/frame_padding"
...>